# How to loose couple trait with config?

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, frame, loose-coupling, config

I want to loose couple my MultiToken pallet to new Dex pallet, so I created MultiToken trait for interface.
[image]
Here I need Config to infer AccountId and OriginFor types

In my Dex pallet I need to add this trati in config
[image]
But I don't really understand what I need to pass in generic of MultiToken

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making your trait generic over `T: Config`, you should make it generic over `AccountId`, and you probably should not include `Origin` anywhere in your interface.

Then, rather than passing `Self`, you should pass `Self::AccountId` into the generic parameter of the configuration.

If you posted your text, instead of screenshots, it would be helpful for us to show you the modified code.